# Evolution and Exchange Server 2007 without MAPI

Tags: email, evolution, exchange

My organization is running an exchange server 2007 with MAPI disabled for security reasons.  How do I connect with evolution?  When I connect using the Microsoft Exchange option I get the error

> The Exchange server is not compatible
>   with Exchange Connector.
>
> The server is running Exchange 5.5.
>   Exchange Connector  supports Microsoft
>   Exchange 2000 and 2003 only.

If I use the Exchange MAPI option I get

> Authentication failed.
>
> MapiLogonProvider:MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR

Which appears to be a network timeout, which confirms that administrators have MAPI turned off.

Comment: It appears that since MAPI is disabled, is there an Exchange ActiveSync option that would work like mobil phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible, at least if you want a reasonably stable solution.  Which would, at this point, also exclude the Exchange MAPI option, even if it were available.

Comment: Thanks.  I've decided to virtualize windows so that I can get access to my calendar and full address book